Place a picture (logo) on the top right corner of the first page of a chapter
I'd like to put a logo on the first page of a chapter page.I'be trying with mini-pages, but it messed up the chapter title
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum} % Voor de voorbeeldtekst

\begin{document}
    
    \chapter{Chapter 1: Introduction}
    
    \lipsum[1-3] % Voorbeeldtekst, gebruik makend van drie paragrafen
    
\end{document}



Your picture shows it overlapping the margins, but not how much.

The following code adds a picture in the top right corner of the text block on the \chapter page:

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\AddToHookNext{shipout/foreground}{%
  \hspace{\dimexpr\hoffset+1in+\oddsidemargin+\textwidth}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-\voffset-1in-\headsep-\headheight-\topmargin-\height}{%
    \makebox[0pt][r]{\includegraphics[height=4\baselineskip]{example-image}}% Your logo
  }%
}
    
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}

The image is positioned into place using the standard page/text block dimensions, setting the logo right-aligned with the text block right margin.
Code can be adjusted to set the image on all pages, or just certain pages.
